# Is path-connected and locally path-connected equivalent to simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Is path-connected and locally path-connected equivalent to simply connected?

I am more confident with the part that simply connected implies path-connected and locally path-connected. And the other way should stand as well. But I am not quite sure how to prove it?

Comment: The circle is path-connected but not simply connected.

Comment: Some people take path connectedness as part of the definition of simply connectedness.

Comment: No - if both path connectedness and locally path-connectedness were equivalent to $P$, then they would be equivalent to each other (as equivalence is an equivalence relation); a contradiction.

Comment: A simply connected space need not be locally connected. Take for example the space $\left(\left\{\frac1n\middle|n\in\Bbb N\right\}\cup\{0\}\right)\times I\ \ 
\cup\ \ I\times\{0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply connected set of course (by definition) is path-connected, but on the other side a path-connected and locally path-connected set need not to be simply connected. The easiest example is an open disk $B \subset \mathbb{R}$  around $0$, with an additional point $0'$, and adding to the topology base a base around $0$, with $0$ substituded with $0'$. Figuratively, $0$ is "doubled".

Any continuous homotopy to this space, starting with a path through $0$, cannot contain $0'$, because of contonuity (the preimage of the paths passing through $0'$ and of the paths passing through $0$ would disconnect $[0,1]$, which is bviously connected) so paths through $0$ and through $0'$ are not homotopically equivalent.